# validate a combination of different fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

aspx page

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="dob_msg_lbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red" Text="invalid date of birth" visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="day_tb" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Width="15px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="/" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="month_ddl" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Jan">January</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Feb">Feb</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Mar">Mar</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Apr">Apr</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="May">May</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Jun">Jun</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Jul">Jul</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Aug">Aug</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Sep">Sep</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Oct">Oct</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Nov">Nov</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Dec">Dec</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="/" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="year_tb" runat="server" Width="30px" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.vb page

```
            Dim dobStr As String = day_tb.Text + " " + month_ddl.SelectedValue + " " + year_tb.Text
            Try
                    dob = Convert.ToDateTime(dobStr)
            Catch ex As Exception
                    dob_msg_lbl.Visible = True
            End Try
```

Currently I am mimicking the asp.net's validation functions by setting `dob_msg_lbl.visible` to `true` when `Convert.ToDateTime` results in an exception.

The problem with such a method is that the validation only occurs when the form is submitted.

I want to validate it on the fly, just like what happens when you use `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Is it to possible to use something such as the `CustomValidator` to validate a combination of `textbox` and `dropdownlist` on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CustomerValidator as explained here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9522/CustomValidator-dependent-on-multiple-controls

Or 
you can create a validate function with your logic, and call it on the Selection change event for dropdown and text change event of TextBox. So anytime, any of those thing changes that will trigger the event and will call your validate function.

Comment: Couldn't get the codes in the link to work. Your 2nd suggestion works fine but I don't want my `Submit` button to cause a `postback` upon click if the validation fails.